# Prevent duplicates for a certain GraphCool model

Tags: sql, graphcool

I have a GraphCool model called `Student` which has a field called `studentNumber`. How can I prevent two (or more) different `Student` nodes with the same `studentNumber`? In SQL databases I was able to create a unique index to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do so is by enabling the "Unique" constraint for a certain field (`studentNumber` in your case for the `Student` model). You can enable constraints in the structure view when editing a model.

Note: Under the hood, this creates a unique index in the database just like you suggested.